# Multiple Choice Generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to make a multiple choice exercise generator. There is a ganerator on the top and a display area underneath, that the generated quiz should be added to display area. In the following, you can see my code, can anyone help me with adding this form from the generator to the display area?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>Programming Project. 2015/2016</title>
<style>
.my-row {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 5px;

  }
  label {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .label-left {
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .label-right {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .error {
    color: #cc0000;
  }
  .highlighted {
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_quest').submit(function(e) {
      var my_errors = false;
      $('.my-row > .error').remove(); 
      $('.my-row').removeClass('highlighted'); 

      $(':text').each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == '') {
           $(this).parent().addClass('highlighted');
           $(this).parent().append('<div class="error">Please provide a  value</div>');
           my_errors = true;
        }

      });
      if (my_errors) {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         e.preventDefault();
         if (!confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?')) {
            return false;
         }

        }

        $ ("#send").click(function() {
       $ (".my-row").append("#displayArea")
       });
        });
        });


       </script>
       </head>
       <body>


       <div id = "generator">
       <form name="my_quest" id="my_quest" action="" method="post">
       <h2>Quiz Generator</h2>
       <div class = "my-row">
       <label for = "question" class="label-left">Question: </label>
        <input type = "text" name = "question" id = "question">
        </div></br>
        <div class = "my-row">
        <label for = "correctAnswer" class = "label-left">Correct answer:   </label>
        <input type = "text" name = "correctAnswer" id="correctAnswer">
        </div></br>
       <div class = "my-row">
        <label for = "incorrectAnswer" class = "label-left">Incorrect  answer: </label>
        <input type = "text" name = "incorrectAnswer" id = "incorrectAnswer">
        </div></br>
        <div class = "my-row">
        <label for = "incorrectAnswer" class = "label-left">Incorrect answer: </label>
        <input type = "text" name="incorrectAnswer" id = "incorrectAnswer">
        </div></br>
          <div class = "my-row">
        <label for = "incorrectAnswer" class = "label-left">Incorrect answer: </label>
        <input type = "text" name = "incorrectAnswer" id = "incorrectAnswer">
        </div></br>


        <div class="my-row">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form">
         </div> 
         </form>
         </div>
         <div id= "displayArea"></div>
         <div><button id= "send">Send</button></div>

       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Your question is not clear. How would you like to show the form inside the display area ? Any picture or sketch you would like to share ?

Comment: @  cafebabe1991 : it is a generator , you write the questions and 4 choices on the generator part and then you should put it to the display area, then second question is added to the first one.